# How to print letters from A-Z in a for loop?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I am trying to print out alphabets from `'A'` to `'Z'`using `for` loop. What I could do is :

```
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {
    echo $char . "\n";
}
```

but what I am trying to achieve is :

```
for($i = 'A'; $i <= 'Z'; $i++){
echo $i . "<br>";
}
```

The above method gives me a ridiculously long chain of alphabets.

Using,

```
for($i = 'A'; $i < 'Z'; $i++){   //note the change of '<=' to '<' 
echo $i;
}
```

does give me alphabets `A` to **`Y`**.

Comment: `for($i = 'A'; $i !== 'AA'; $i++){`

Comment: why? What's wrong with the first loop you wrote? Why do you need a counter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `$i` reaches `Z`, it's still `<= Z`, so it echoes out and increments, then tests again to see if the result of that is `<= Z`.... the problem is that PHP uses [Perl-style character incrementing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).... incrementing `Z` gives `AA`, and `AA <== Z` is true in an alphabetic comparison, so it continues echoing, incrementing and testing through `AB`, `AC`, to `AZ`, `BA`, `BB` etc.....

it's only when it reaches `YZ` that the next increment gives `ZZ` which isn't `<= Z` and it terminates

The solution is to avoid using a `<=` comparison, but to use a `!==` comparison, and that needs to be a comparison against the next increment from `Z`, ie `AA`, so

```
for($i = 'A'; $i !== 'AA'; $i++){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this one! :D Really interesting :)

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: This actually explains _why_ the loop behaves as it does, rather than just providing an alternative method. +1

Answer (score 2):

As uppercase alphabetical characters are following each other in the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), you can use the [`chr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) function

```
for ($i = 65; $i <= 90; $i++) {
    echo(chr($i).' ');
}
```

65 is 'A' in the ASCII Table and 90 is 'Z'

For code clearness, you could either do : (using [`ord`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) function)

```
for ($i = ord('A'); $i <= ord('Z'); $i++) {
    echo(chr($i).' ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop loop `AA`. As the next element after `Z` is `AA`

```
for($i = 'A'; $i != 'AA'; $i++){   //note the change of '<' to '<=' 
echo $i."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the logic , but could you please tell me why `$i<=Z` doesn't work?

Comment: Because it will compared as string so it match start from first character

Comment: Next `AA` compare with `Z` as string comparision `A` compare with `Z`(from left to right) so it will return true, And repeat

Answer (score 1):

With simple **do-while** loop:

```
$l = "A";
do {
    echo $l;
} while($l++ != "Z");
```

The output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
$apl_arr = range('A', 'Z');
for($ii=0;$ii<count($apl_arr);$ii++)
    echo $apl_arr[$ii],',';
exit;
```

may this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i made a mistake in my previous answer, Please try this:

```
<?php
for ($i = 'A'; $i !== 'AA'; $i++)
    echo "$i\n";
?>
```

Answer (score -5):

I think you should specify the language you are trying to get this printed with. The simplest answer I can think of is in bash with the following:

```
for i in {A..Z}; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: The question is tagged as PHP, so that's the language specified.

Comment: he did mention it. Its 100 % clear that he tries it in PHP.